# Modify minified js file after minification

Tags: javascript, maven, minify, anonymous-function, bundling-and-minification

I have minification applied in javascript file. I want to wrap that minified file with

`(function(){` **file content here** `})()`
.
**OR**

Any other way I can achieve this.

***Basically I want my files to be anonymously wrapped.***

I am using following maven plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <preProcessAggregates>true</preProcessAggregates>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <disableOptimizations>false</disableOptimizations>
        <failOnWarning>false</failOnWarning>
        <force>true</force>
        <gzip>false</gzip>
        <nomunge>true</nomunge>
        <jswarn>false</jswarn>
        <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
        <useProcessedResources>true</useProcessedResources>
        <aggregations>
            <aggregation>
                <insertNewLine>false</insertNewLine>
                <output>${basedir}/target/web/js/minified.js</output>
                <inputDir>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/js/app</inputDir>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.js</include>
                </includes>
            </aggregation>
        </aggregations>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/lib/**</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*-min.js</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.min.js</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*-min.css</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*.min.css</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/target</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**EDIT**
I can achieve this with putting every files in anonymous function and at build time, merging and minifying. But instead of putting this in every file, i want to put this only on merged file.

I want to wrap in anonymous function so that code cannot be accessible through console.

Comment: Why would you like to do this? I need to understand to help you better

Answer (score 1):

You should use an asset pipeline tool to take a deep control over your configuration.

You can consider to use [WUIC](http://wuic.github.io) and extend it according to your need.

You can use the `maven-plugin`, enable `YUICompressor` support and then just write a custom `ObjectBuilderInspector` that will specify to the aggregator your custom `Transformer` that wraps your content.

Please find some piece of code bellow, you will find the documentation [here](http://wuic.github.io/wuic-documentation.html) and the samples [here](https://github.com/wuic/wuic-samples/tree/wuic-0.5.x-snapshot/build-time-sample) and [here](https://github.com/wuic/wuic-samples/tree/wuic-0.5.x-snapshot/js-sprite-sample).

## pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.wuic.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>static-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <xml>src/main/resources/wuic.xml</xml>
                <properties>src/main/resources/wuic.properties</properties>
                <output>${project.build.finalName}</output>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.github.wuic.extensions</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wuic-yuicompressor</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

## wuic.xml:

```
<wuic>
    <heaps>
        <heap id="scripts">
            <nut-path>*/lib/*</nut-path>
            <nut-path>*/*-min.js</nut-path>
            <nut-path>*/*.min.js</nut-path>
            <nut-path>*/*-min.css</nut-path>
            <nut-path>*/*.min.css</nut-path>
        </heap>
    </heaps>
</wuic>
```

## wuic.properties

```
# for resources in classpath (src/main/resources)
c.g.wuic.dao.wildcard=true
c.g.wuic.dao.basePath=/js/app
c.g.wuic.facade.additionalBuilderInspectorClasses=com.your.app.MyInspector
```

## Your custom transformer that is plugged thanks to an inspector

```
public class MyInspector implements ObjectBuilderInspector, Pipe.Transformer<ConvertibleNut> {

        @Override
    public <T> T inspect(T object) {
        if (object instanceof TextAggregatorEngine) {
            TextAggregatorEngine.class.cast(object).addTransformer(this);
        }

        return object;
    }

    @Override
    public void transform(InputStream is, OutputStream os, ConvertibleNut convertible) throws IOException {
        if (convertible.getNutType().equals(NutType.JAVASCRIPT)) {
            os.write("(function(){".getBytes());
            IOUtils.copyStream(is, os);
            os.write("})();".getBytes());
        } else {
            IOUtils.copyStream(is, os);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canAggregateTransformedStream() {
        return false;
    }
}
```